# Java List to JSON array using Jackson with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: arrays, json, list, utf-8, jackson

Now I'm trying to convert Java List object to JSON array, and struggling to convert UTF-8 strings. I've tried all followings, but none of them works.

Settings.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Test#1.

```
// Using writeValueAsString
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(list2);
```

Test#2.

```
// Using Bytes
final byte[] data = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(list2);
String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Test#3.

```
// Using ByteArrayOutputStream with new String()
final OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mapper.writeValue(os, list2);
final byte[] data = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) os).toByteArray();
String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Test#4.

```
// Using ByteArrayOutputStream
final OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mapper.writeValue(os, list2);
String json = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) os).toString("UTF-8");
```

Test#5.

```
// Using writeValueAsString
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(list2);
```

Test#6.

```
// Using writeValue
mapper.writeValue(out, list2);
```

Like I said, none of above works. All displays characters like "???". I appreciate your helps. I'm using Servlet to send JSON response to clients.

This problem only happens when I write java.util.List object. If I write single data object, e.g. customer object in below example, then there is no ??? characters, and UTF-8 is working with the following code.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(customer);
out.print(json);
```

Comment: What is *list2*? What is *ow*? What is *out*?

Comment: Test #1 works with pure Java strings. There is no encoding involved. If Test #1 doesn't work, then the ??? characters are already part of *list2* or they are introduced at a later stage not shown in your question. Please provide more context. At which point do you see the ??? characters?

Comment: @Torino I forgot to add those. I've updated my original post. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Torino Regarding characters inside list2 object, I've tested and the characters are just fine (not ???), which means characters will be broken during the JSON write process. If I write just single object, then there's no problem. This only happens when I try to write java.util.List using Jackson.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer was very simple. You need to specify UTF-8 charset encoding in response.setContentType too.

```
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

Then, many of above code will work correctly. I will leave my question as is, since it will show you several ways of writing JSON to clients.

Answer (score 2):

On RequestMapping in Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/get/sth",
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = { "application/json;**charset=UTF-8**" })
```

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, if you're writing the content to a file, then you need to specify the encoding when you create the FileWriter in Java 17:

```java
try (FileWriter jsonFileWriter = new FileWriter(tmpFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    objectMapper.writeValue(jsonFileWriter, report);
}
```

If you want to convert your Java object to a JSON string with UTF-8 encoding, it ideally should not be a worry since Java's String is natively in UTF-16. You don't need to worry about the encoding until you need to write this string to a byte stream, or out to a file (see above) or over the network.

But if you need to get byte[] in UTF-8 encoding from a String, you can use `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. Like

```java
public byte[] toJsonStringUTF8(Object yourObject) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
    return jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```